# How to make a JFrame (with timer) open another JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, splash-screen, multiple-instances

New here - my first question. Anyway, I am here because I want to make a JFrame, that is timed for 10000 milliseconds, I think, and then when it closes, it should open another (which is in another class). I already did the timer part, not the 'closing the timed JFrame, and opening another' part.

I remember doing this, and found an answer. It went something like `NewClass.show()` ('NewClass' is the class name that should open) and then you type in `OldClass.dispose()` ('OldClass' is the class name that should close).

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SplashScreen extends JPanel {

public SplashScreen() {
 setOpaque(false);
 setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loading game...");
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    SplashScreen background = new SplashScreen();
    frame.add(background);

    Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
           //I want to place my code here so then this class will close, and then the other class will open
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();

    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image image = toolkit.getImage("Waiting.png");
    Point hotSpot = new Point(0,0);
    Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Cursor");
    frame.setCursor(cursor);

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int w = frame.getSize().width;
    int h = frame.getSize().height;
    int x = (dim.width - w) / 2;
    int y = (dim.height - h) / 2;

    frame.setLocation(x, y);

    JButton button = new JButton();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image a=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Splash Screen.gif");
    g.drawImage(a,0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height,this);
    super.paint(g);

    }
}
```

I didn't make the second class (which would be called 'LoadingScreen.class', but I will, and it will just have 'JSomethings' or whatever (like JFrame, JPanel, etc...)

I can make the second class, but all I want is the first class to close after the timer finishes at 10 seconds, or 10000 milliseconds, and then automatically open the second class.

Thanks

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: *"which would be called 'SplashScreen.class'"*  Why not use [`java.awt.SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) for this?  Java Web Start also supports a splash image.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the call to your second class like below

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
       //I want to place my code here so then this class will close, and then the other class will open

       //SplashScreen screen = new SplashScreen();
       //screen.showGUI();
    }
});
```

Another good practice is to call `frame.setVisible(true)` at the last so that you wont find any drift in the frame position on the screen.

Comment: thank you for the second advice - adding `frame.setVisible(true)` last, but I still don't get what you mean about calling that code to the second class. I'm new to Java, and this is my first program I'm making without using YouTube. when I try what you did, it just showed the first class, but didn't show the JFrame in the second class. Did I do something wrong? I got confused. Basically, all I want is to dispose the LoadingScreen.class file, and when SplashScreen.class has disposed after the 10 seconds, LoadingScreen.class should show. Sometimes, Java can be a little annoying and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your second class is like,

```
public class LoadingScreen extends JFrame   
{    
    public LoadingScreen(String title)  
    {   
        super(title);  
    }

    public void showGUI()   
    {
        //  Do whatever you want
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You just have to call,

```
LoadingScreen loadScreen = new LoadingScreen("Loading screen....");
loadscreen.showGUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call frame.setVisoble(true) dont you get an error non static method cannot be referenced from static context?